# How to update a html table without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I have the following `playlist table` which I display from my database. When I click one of the buttons in this `playlist table`, I want to update the `Songs` HTML table that gets generated from clicking one of these buttons without updating the page.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Item4.Playlists)
{
      //Populate list with PlaylistIDs
      result = item.Playlist_ID + "." + result;

      //For each Playlist generate a button
      <td onclick="showSongs('@result', '@item.Playlist_ID');">
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Playlist_Name)
          <span id="@item.Playlist_ID@item.Playlist_Name" style="display: none;" class="resize">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Playlist_Name)</span>
      </td>
}
```

This the HTML `Songs table` that I want to update without refreshing the page:

```
 <div id='PlaylistsFromDB' class="Playlists">
        <!-- this is the container that will hold all the uploaded songs by the user-->
        <div class="container3">
             <table>
                    <tr Style="color: white;">
                        <th>
                             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item3.Song_Name)
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr Style="color: white;" class="items">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Item3.songsList)
                        {
                            <td onclick="myAudioFunction1('@item.Song_Name', '@item.Song_ID', '@item.Song_Audio')">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Song_Name)
                                <span id="@item.Song_ID@item.Song_Name" style="display: none;" class="resize">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Song_Name)</span>
                                <span id="@item.Song_ID@item.Song_Audio" style="display: none;" class="resize">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Song_Audio)</span>
                           </td>
                        }
                    </tr>
           </table>
         </div>     
     </div>
```

This is my JS method `showSongs` which returns the ID of which playlist was clicked:

```
function showSongs(playlistNumber, currentPlaylistID) {
  var ArrayOfLists = playlistNumber.split('.');

  for (let i = 0; i < ArrayOfLists.length; i++) {
      if (ArrayOfLists[i] == currentPlaylistID) {
          var Id = "songsinplaylist" + currentPlaylistID;
          alert(Id);
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '/Home/GetID',
              dataType: "html",
              data: {
                  dataID: currentPlaylistID,
              },
              success: function (data) {
              },
              error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                  //alert(textStatus);
              }

          });
          break;
      }
  }


  document.getElementById("songsdefault").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("home_first").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("PlaylistsFromDB").style.display = "initial";
}
```

This is the controller that the JS method triggers:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetID(string dataID)
    {
        FetchPlaylistData();
        GetListofPlaylistIDs();
        String id;
        id = HttpContext.Session.GetString("User_ID");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataID))
        {
            ConnectionString();
            con.Open();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandText = "update Consumer set CurrentPlaylistID = '" + dataID + "'  where User_ID ='" + id + "'";
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("CurrentPlaylistID", dataID);
            //Runs a query that obtains all the songs for the current playlist
            FetchSongData();
            return RedirectToAction("Update", Tuple.Create(consumer, storage, songsModel, playlistModel));
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Update", Tuple.Create(consumer, storage, songsModel, playlistModel));
    }
```

Comment: Word of advice: DO NOT(!!) construct your SQL query by concatenating strings with user input. Use [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) at the very least - https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: For the actual question, have you attempted a solution that you're stuck at? I think the best ways is to either return the HTML from the controller action and replace/insert it via JavaScript or use a framework for frontend rendering instead if you plan on making your webpage more SPA-like (like React/Angular/Vue.js).

Comment: If you want to change html with js,you need to return new data in `GetID` action,and change the html with the data in ajax success.

Comment: @Xerillio thank you, I had no idea you could use something like parameters. I will start using that from now on.

Comment: @Yiyi You as for returning the HTML on ajax success how would I return a razor view through JavaScript? Since I haven't found a way that's why I thought I could just refresh the table or just re-run the certain div that contains the table.

Comment: @Yiyi You Actually I see what you mean from the controller the new songs get returned into JS to the variable data, but how can I extract the songs model from data?

Comment: You can pass a list of songs to ajax rather than IActionResult type data,so that the data you get in ajax is the songs.Then you can generate html with the list of songs.